# How can I make the footer color match the header color?

Tags: html, css, styles, border, footer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>OrderID</th>
            <th>Order Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>USA</td>
            <td>1000</td>
            <td>$1,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>USA</td>
            <td>1001</td>
            <td>$700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CA</td>
            <td>1002</td>
            <td>$2,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CA</td>
            <td>1003</td>
            <td>$1,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <tfoot>
                <td colspan="2">Total</td>
                <td>$5,000</td>
            </tfoot>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #c4dcf3;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
    padding: 10px;
}

th {
    background-color: #427fef; 
    color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #eef7ff;
}

tfoot {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #427fef;
}
```

In this example I am creating a table with several rows. I wanted the header and border to match in color while the odd rows of the table are a different color. I tried keeping the properties of the header and border the same but the didn't work. The code for the odd rows seem to override the desired color for the footer. I linked styles.css to the html document but the footer still isn't showing up like its suppose to.

Comment: Read up about the correct syntax for an HTML table at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table In particular, put your headings into a thead element, the content into a tbody element and the footer into a tfoot element.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the **tfoot** tag incorrectly, see this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tfoot.asp

I recommend reorganizing your html like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>OrderID</th>
                <th>Order Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>USA</td>
                <td>1000</td>
                <td>$1,300</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>USA</td>
                <td>1001</td>
                <td>$700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CA</td>
                <td>1002</td>
                <td>$2,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CA</td>
                <td>1003</td>
                <td>$1,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Total</td>
                <td>$5,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Now you can set styles with reference to the **tfoot** and **tbody**: `tbody > tr`

Refactored styles.css:

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #c4dcf3;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
    padding: 10px;
}

th {
    background-color: #427fef; 
    color: white;
}

tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #eef7ff;
}

tfoot > tr {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #427fef;
}
```

Now your last row is blue :)